# Laravel 5.5 - Api using Passport did not Authenticated

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-5.5

I am using Passport package of API Authentication.

Issue is that `Auth::attempt` is working on login method. and `Auth::user()` also working but in other method it did not work and return `NULL`.

**My Login Method**

In login first I check Authentication by `Auth::check()` - it did not work.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), TRUE);
        if(!empty($data)) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Already Authenticated'], 200);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $email = $data['email'];
                $pass = $data['password'];
                $credentials = array('email' => $email, 'password' =>$pass);
                if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){    
                    $user = Auth::user();  // here it work
                    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                    return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
                }
                else {
                    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here Authentication did not work.

```
public function details()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
    }
```

Below I have given my routes which I have written in my api.php file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {
    Route::post("/login", ['uses'=>'UserController@login']);
    Route::get("/details", ['uses'=>'UserController@details']);
});
```

If I tried like in below, then also it did not work.
But If i removed `->middleware('auth:api')` then it will work.

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return array(
    1 => "John",
    2 => "Mary",
    3 => "Steven"
    );
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

above url is given `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`

I did a lot of research but unable to solve my issue.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post your routes also

Comment: @MayankPandeyz , I have updated and mention my routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Headers on your request

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
```